# Why RID (Bookmark) lookup is not being shown in execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, lookup, non-clustered-index

I tried to examine RID (foremerly bookmark) lookup by creating a heap table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerAddress] 
( 
[CustomerID] [int], 
[AddressID] [int], 
[ModifiedDate] [datetime] 
); 
GO 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX x 
ON dbo.CustomerAddress(CustomerID, AddressID);
```

Then, I tried the following query to inestigate execution plan:

```
SELECT CustomerID, AddressID, ModifiedDate 
FROM dbo.CustomerAddress 
WHERE CustomerID = 29485;
```

But, using MSSMS I cannot see RID lookup in the execution plan:

[image]

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2 (version 10.50.4000.0) service pack 2.

PS: This question is based on Aaron Bertrand's [article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2195/identifying-key-and-rid-lookup-issues-and-how-to-resolve/).

Comment: How many rows are in the table?

Comment: My original thought is the query optimizer decided a table scan was faster than using the index w/ RID lookup.  50k+ rows surprised me, though.  Maybe Aaron can explain...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A table scan means SQL Server does not use your index.  It reads from the "heap".  A "heap" is the data storage for tables without a clustered index.

Since it does not touch the index at all, SQL Server does not need a RID lookup to go from the index to the heap.

The reason is probably that SQL Server estimates there might be more than +/- 100 rows for one customer.  The optimizer will try to avoid a large numbers of lookups.

You could try again with an index on just `(CustomerID)`, or by adding an `AddresID` to your `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks. I tailored the data so that few number of rows are returned and the optimized finally decides to do RID lookup.